# OpenWRT, cross or native compilation?

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, openwrt

For the first time I'm facing to implement a software on an embedded system like Raspberry (ARM CPU) and/or OLinuXino (MIPS).

I just developed the most part of my application on a XUbuntu PC Intel x64.

Now, to avoid a waste of time I need to setup:

1. a virtual machine in charge of testing my sw (just done);
2. a build environment to produce the binaries for the real hardware.

About the point 1 I have already installed the image [openwrt-15.05-x86-generic-combined-ext4.img.gz](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/vmware) on a VirtualBox virtual machine.

My development environment is equipped with **g++** and [**CMake**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599965/how-to-download-a-toolchain-for-cross-compilation-in-cmake-from-separate-file).

I googled a lot searching for information and tutorials about how to cross compile applications on OpenWRT, but unfortunately it is not a trivial task. So, I have many questions to post:

1. is [OpenWrt-Toolchain-x86-64_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.11.Linux-x86_64.tar.bz2](https://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/x86/64/OpenWrt-Toolchain-x86-64_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.11.Linux-x86_64.tar.bz2) the right one for the **virtual machine** I have installed?
2. is [OpenWrt-Toolchain-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.12.Linux-x86_64.tar.bz2](https://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/OpenWrt-Toolchain-ar71xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.12.Linux-x86_64.tar.bz2) the right one for the **Raspberry (ARM)** platform?
3. is [OpenWrt-Toolchain-brcm63xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.12.Linux-x86_64.tar.bz2](https://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/brcm63xx/generic/OpenWrt-Toolchain-brcm63xx-generic_gcc-5.2.0_musl-1.1.12.Linux-x86_64.tar.bz2) the right one for the **OLinuXino (MIPS)** platform?
4. how can I [correctly setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599965/how-to-download-a-toolchain-for-cross-compilation-in-cmake-from-separate-file) my cross compiling environment for CMake?
5. cross compiling it's an hard task so, is it possibile to [build straight on the OpenWRT](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=51411) (virtual or physical)?
6. If point 5 is possibile, I did not find packages for CMake, SQLite3 (DEV) and Log4CXX. Where can I find them? Have I to recompile from scratch?

Thank you so much for your time and your attention!

Comment: https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=310381